# Correlation between two multivariate measures

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, multivariate-distribution

I'm reading a paper, but I'm with a problem. The authors say:
Let $\boldsymbol{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_p)^T$ be a vector $m \times 1$ whose the estimative of variance is proportional to $\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}}$, let $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ be a mean vector $m \times 1$ and $\boldsymbol{W} = A(\boldsymbol{X - \mu})$ or $\boldsymbol{\hat{W}} = (\hat{D}\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}\hat{D})^{-1/2}\hat{D}$. The paper affirms that

$$
Corr(X_j, \hat{W}_j) = diag\{(\hat{D}\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}\hat{D})^{1/2}\}, \quad j = 1, \ldots, p.
$$

My question is: How to calculate $\hat{D}$ or $(\hat{D}\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}\hat{D})^{1/2}$?

The paper is: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/anzs.12144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the paper (p. 102):[image: Relevant Section]
So if $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the sample covariance matrix, $\hat{D}$ is just the diagonal matrix where the $i^{th}$ element is equal to the multiplicative inverse of the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of $\hat{\Sigma}$. Since the matrix $(\hat{D}\hat{\Sigma}\hat{D})$ is square, we know that $(\hat{D}\hat{\Sigma}\hat{D})^\frac{1}{2}$ is just the 1 divided by the square root for each element of the resulting diagonal matrix (See [Powers of a Diagonal Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Powers_of_diagonal_matrices)).